# Repeated measures test of (un)equal variance

Tags: variance, repeated-measures, levenes-test

I have a repeated measures design with two groups and two measurements of a value $x$ (the minimum signal level needed for reliable detection). I measured $x$ with procedure A and procedure B. One group ran procedure A followed by procedure B and the other ran B followed by A. The values of $x$ measured for each group and procedure seem well approximated by a normal distribution.

The expectation, and reality, is that there will be no effect of procedure or group, nor an interaction, on the mean value of $x$ but that variance of $x$ will be slightly larger when measured with procedure A. My $N$ is large (~1000) so that I can detect small differences in variance without violating, too badly, the assumptions of the repeated measures ANOVA used to test for differences in the mean.

For testing for (un)equal variance between two independent groups, I would normally use Levene's test (or an F-test or Bartlettt's test). For a repeated measures ANOVA I use Mauchly's sphericity test, but my gut is telling me that a test of sphericity is not the same thing as a test of equal variance of $x$.

For a repeated measures design, what is the appropriate test of (un)equal variance?